# string comparison for hash keys in perl

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I am having an hash map in perl like this:

```
MAP_MESSAGE_TO_NUMBER => {
     'Hello World, I am XYZ'    => 11,
     'I am using Stack Overflow for Guidance'   => 12,
     'Programming is good!' => 13,
},
```

in my Perl code i am trying to make a match with hash key and if match happens i just return the corresponding hash value ( number ).

My code is working fine.

```
my $Strtomatch = 'Hello World, I am XYZ!';
if ( some condition ) {
    my $val =   MAP_MESSAGE_TO_NUMBER->{$Strtomatch};
    # some code will use the return value 
    doSomethingWith $val;  
}
```

My question here is:
  if you will see the value of variable $Strtomatch has one extra character '!' which is not present in original hash map. So because of this my hash map does not returns any value.

My question is how can i make this more generic so that i can make comparison even if part of strings match.

even few characters match its fine to return the value.

Let me know.

I am not really sure how i can use regular expression here because i am doing comparison for a value in hash map with a value coming from other function. 
I am very technical and not too good with programming, trying things to learn.

Comment: This can be solved by iterating all the keys in the hash and keeping the closest match.  If your hash is very large or performance is critical, this may not be a viable option.

Comment: Your idea is - at least theoretically - problematic because the return value possibly is no scalar anymore, since more than one key might match `$Strtomatch`. Of course you could just select the first one you find, if that's what you desire.

Comment: ... but what's the 'first one' when talking about hashes? In this case, it might be a better idea to use two sequences instead: the first one with keys, the second one - with values.

Comment: Or an array of two-element arrays.

Comment: I think you have to rethink your strategy. Hash lookup is for exact matches, and it is not a practical way to look up partial matches. You're going to have to give more detail on what kind of partial matches are okay for anyone to have a clue on how to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %msg_to_number = ( 
     'Hello World, I am XYZ'    => 11,
     'I am using Stack Overflow for Guidance'   => 12,
     'Programming is good!' => 13,
);

my $str_to_match = 'Hello World, I am XYZ!';
#note - grep returns a list. We chuck any duplicate hits away. 
my ( $first_match ) = grep { $str_to_match =~ m/\Q$_\E/ } keys %msg_to_number;

print "$first_match   =  $msg_to_number{$first_match}\n";
```

Note - the pattern match in the grep is reversed. You check if your string matches a key in the hash, and return that if it does. It'll only work if your key is a substring (or exact match) of your primary string.

And it only gets a 'first' match, so practically speaking - if there are duplicates, the result will be random. So make sure your hash keys are sufficiently unique.

E.g:

```
my $str_to_match = 'Hello World, I am XYZ!Programming is good!!!!!one';
my ( $first_match ) = grep { $str_to_match =~ m/\Q$_\E/ } keys %msg_to_number;
print "$first_match   =  $msg_to_number{$first_match}\n";
```

Will give your randomly:

```
Programming is good!   =  13
Hello World, I am XYZ   =  11
```

As an alternative - one possiblity is perform a common transform on input/output, which makes it 'blind' to the differences.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %msg_to_number = ( 
     'Hello World, I am XYZ'    => 11,
     'I am using Stack Overflow for Guidance'   => 12,
     'Programming is good!' => 13,
);

my $str_to_match = 'Hello World, I am XYZ!!!!!';
my $transformed_match = $str_to_match =~ s/\W//gr;

my ( $first_match ) = grep { s/\W//gr =~ m/^\Q$transformed_match\E$/i } keys %msg_to_number;
print "$first_match   =  $msg_to_number{$first_match}\n";
```

This strips `\W` which is "not word" characters (like punctuation and whitespace) and compares the two like that. It means your matches are a bit fuzzier, and will allow arbitrary exclamation marks, spacing etc.

If you want to handle a default case, then the very handy. `//` operator is what you want.

```
return $msg_to_number{$first_match} // "default value here " ;
```

(or you can just test defined on `$first_match`)

For case insentive matching, the `i` modifier to the regex will do the trick as in the second example.

Comment: ok so lets say if i do this but no match happened for the string passed in. How can i capture that and return a default value in that case ?

Comment: and also how can your solution be converted so that it do comparison in lower case. That is first both strings gets converted into lower case and then gets compare. I think this will cover maximum corner cases as well

Comment: Former use `//` latter use `i` regex modifier.

Comment: one question in your second approach partial matching of expression does not happens whereas in your first approach it does happens. My question is how can second approach be modified to have that flexibility. ( considering that all hash keys are unique and nothing repeats )

Comment: like for example:  if hash map has "I am suppose to matched" and input string is "I am suppose to be matched". Then in this case first approach do match and second approach does not. So how second approach be modified to handle this case , any suggestions

Comment: Ask a new question - that's a very different sort of problem - you're not comparing substrings any more, but partial matches. That means you need to have a clear idea of what does or doesn't match..

Comment: asked question seperately here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636400/comparison-of-string-against-key-value-pair-in-hash-map-perl, let me know if you have any suggestions

Answer (score -1):

You can compile a regex outside of an `=~` operator using the `qr` quote-like operator. The downside to this approach is that now you have to iterate over the search keys to see if any patterns match. It will be much slower than a simple hash lookup.

```
use constant MAP_MESSAGE_TO_NUMBER => (
  [qr/Hello World, I am XYZ/,                  11],
  [qr/I am using Stack Overflow for Guidance/, 12],
  [qr/Programming is good!/,                   13],
);

my $Strtomatch = 'Hello World, I am XYZ!';
if ($some_condition) {
  foreach my $map (MAP_MESSAGE_TO_NUMBER) {
    my ($pattern, $val) = @$map;
    if ($Strtomatch =~ $pattern) {
      # some code will use the return value 
      doSomethingWith $val;
      # optionally exit the loop at this point with `last`, or store multiple match results 
    }
  }
  # optionally check if any match was found and print an error if not
}
```

We can't use a hash as the primary datastruture because our regexes will become unblessed, so I used an array of arrays here. If you want to use a hash you can take a look at Tie::RegexpHash and/or Tie::Hash::Regex.

Comment: Er, no. In Perl hash keys are always strings.

Comment: I've been writing too much Ruby. Thanks @mob. Corrected. It worked but it was unblessing the Regexps and treating them like strings.