# comparison of string against key-value pair in hash map perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, hash

I have key-value pairs in a hash map in Perl. Assuming all keys are unique.

for example like this :

```
my %msg_to_number = ( 
 'Hello World, I am XYZ'    => 11,
 'I am using Stack Overflow for Guidance'   => 12,
 'Programming is good!' => 13,
);
```

now if input strings against which I want to compare is like this:

```
str1 = Hello World, I am XYZ;
str2 = Hello World, I am XYZ and ABC;
```

so below code maps str1 to hash map key correctly but
for str2 it fails.

My question is how can i modify below code to make it working for case both cases.  That is :  making code work for str1 and str2 as well. Hash map should return 11 for both str1 and str2. That is even key in hash map matches a part of string in comparison or complete string it should return match.  (I am assuming partial match case will occur with words in beginning of sentence to be compared against, this simplifies things a bit)

right now below code makes comparison by removing characters like !, # and so on, converting to lower case and then match.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %msg_to_number = ( 
 'Hello World, I am XYZ'    => 11,
 'I am using Stack Overflow for Guidance'   => 12,
 'Programming is good!' => 13,
);

my $str_to_match = 'Hello World, I am XYZ!!!!!';
my $transformed_match = $str_to_match =~ s/\W//gr;

my ( $first_match ) = grep { s/\W//gr =~ m/^\Q$transformed_match\E$/i } keys     
%msg_to_number;
print "$first_match   =  $msg_to_number{$first_match}\n";
```

I have tried playing with regex for above code but was not able to make it work.  if someone can suggest some changes or different method( suggestion )to do same will be great.  ( original logic which code is doing currently plus partial comparison ). This is a follow up question on stack overflow.

Thanks

Updated:
Example of what should match and what should not match.

Assume below hash map:
    my %msg_to_number = ( 
     'Hello World, I am XYZ'    => 11,
     'I am using Stack Overflow for Guidance'   => 12,
     'Programming is good!' => 13,
    );

```
str1 = Hello World, I am XYZ
str2 = Hello World
str3 = Hello World, I am XYZ, ABC and EFG.
```

so in above str1 and str2 should match
whereas str3 no match.

As i said even if starting part is partial match then it should be match.

let me know if this clears the use case

Comment: Can you give some examples of what should and shouldn't match? It'll be hard to answer this question without that. But the typical trick would be - remove the pattern anchors on the regex, and then a substring match will work - as noted in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373587/string-comparison-for-hash-keys-in-perl/33374145?noredirect=1#comment55046671_33374145l) - in the first example I gave, there's no anchors so it substring matches.

Comment: Nit: you said "assuming all keys are unique". There's no assumption here. They **have** to be unique---that's the definition of a hash!

Comment: @MattJacob: by unique i mean to say pattern thye will match against will be unique

Comment: added an example of what should match and what not in questions

Comment: What result do you want for the string `'Hello World, I am XYZ!!!!!  Programming is good!`?

Comment: This `\W` will always hound you. It strips all non-words. You can actually see already, you've molded your test `'Hello World, I am XYZ!!!!!` to have an outcome that will match cropped key. In the real world this will always fail given a partial key match. Also, you don't need `\Q .. \E` since there are no metachars in _word_ characters since you've already stripped them. The best you could do is match a substring (ie. lose the anchors). But, why even do that, just use `substr()` its a lot faster. Nice idea though.

Comment: The cleanest approach might be to construct a regex using all the keys within a big alternation. Then do a single pass regex on the $input. How many keys do you have? The regex engine will construct a trie that makes the search very fast.\

Answer (score 0):

This may be as simple as:

```
my ( $first_match ) = grep { s/\W//gr =~ m/\Q$transformed_match\E/i } keys %msg_to_number;
```

Remove the pattern anchors, and provided `$transformed_match` is a substring of the (transformed) key, then it'll match.

Or you can reverse that - so if the *key* is the substring, it matches:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %msg_to_number = ( 
 'Hello World, I am XYZ'    => 11,
 'I am using Stack Overflow for Guidance'   => 12,
 'Programming is good!' => 13,
);

my $str_to_match = 'Hello World, I am XYZ and ABC!!!!!';
my $transformed_match = $str_to_match =~ s/\W//gr;

my ( $first_match ) = grep { my $tr_key = s/\W//gr; $transformed_match =~ m/$tr_key/i or $tr_key =~ m/$transformed_match/ } keys %msg_to_number;
print "$first_match   =  $msg_to_number{$first_match}\n";
```

(There may be a way to do the transform-and-match within the regex - I'm not 100% sure. But it's probably not a great idea anyway!)

Comment: This will fail for condition when there is a lower case and upper case difference. For example:  Hello World, I am xyz and ABC!!!!! ,  for this case it will fail but was working before.

Comment: If only there was some flag that you could put in your pattern match to make it case insensitive. Something like `i` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but it seems that you need a three way match. If you use REGXs, you need to make sure that you either match all cases you want, or mismatch all cases you do not want. The following script may be closer to what you need. It matches (1) your input string, (2) your HASH KEY, and (3) what you appear to be looking for.

```
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   my %msg_to_number = ( 
    'Hello World, I am XYZ'                    => 11,
    'I am using Stack Overflow for Guidance'   => 12,
    'Programming is good!'                     => 13,
   );

   while(<DATA>)
   {
       chomp;
       foreach my $k (keys %msg_to_number)
       {
           print "$_, $msg_to_number{$k}\n" if $_ =~ /Hello World/ and $k =~ /Hello World/;
       }
   }
   exit(0);

   __DATA__
   Hello World
   Hello World, I am ABC
   I am using Stack Overflow for Guidance
   Programming is good
   Hello World, I am ABC, DEF, GHI
```

Here is the output:

```
Hello World, 11
Hello World, I am ABC, 11
Hello World, I am ABC, DEF, GHI, 11
```

Comment: What does this accomplish? You're matching a defined string against the input and the keys of the hash. Where does that string come from?